# About AST construction in LL1 non recursive parser

Tags: java, parsing, syntax, trees

I have implemented a LL1 parser in a non recursive approach with a explicit stack.

The following algorithm is from the Dragon Book:

```
set zp to point to the first symbol of w;
set X to the top stack symbol;
while ( X != $ ) { /* stack is not empty */
    if ( X is a ) 
       pop the stack and advance zp;
    else if ( X is a terminal )
       error();
    else if ( M[X, a] is an error entry )
       error();
    else if ( M[X,a] = X -+ Y1Y2 Yk ) {
       output the production X -+ YlY2 - . Yk;
       pop the stack;
       push Yk, Yk-1,. . . , Yl onto the stack, with Yl on top;

    set X to the top stack symbol;
}
```

The book says:

> The parser is controlled by a program that considers X, the symbol on
>   top of the stack, and a, the current input symbol. If X is a
>   nonterminal, the parser chooses an X-production by consulting entry
>   M[X, a] of the parsing table IM. **(Additional code could be executed
>   here, for example, code to construct a node in a parse tree.)**
>   Otherwise, it checks for a match between the terminal X and current
>   input symbol a.

However i need more info on how to construct the expression tree nodes under this approach. I have a node hierarchy of UnaryOperator, BinaryOperator, etc but dont know where to instanciate it.

Yet i havent found any simple example of this (with for example the arithmetic language).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens just as the cited text from the book explains: when you expand a nonterminal via its grammar rule (given by `M[X, a]`), then you can create a corresponding node.

Say you have rules of the following form:

```
Term -> Factor Term'
Term' -> * Term | / Term | ε

Factor -> x | y | ... (simplified for individual numbers, letters, what-have-you)
```

Then, once you expand `Term -> Factor Term'` you can create a `Term` node with two child nodes. When you successfully parse the first number via the `Factor -> ...` rule (this is the first `if` in your example code now) you can attribute this number to the already created `Factor` node.

Next, you expand for example `Term' -> * Term` via `M[Term',*]` and create a new `Term` node.

Continuing, you will parse the `*` and annotate it at your `Term'` node, expand `Term -> Factor Term'` once more, thus creating two more nodes, successfully parse a `Factor` and annotate its number to the second `Factor` node and finally, on end of input you will parse `Term'` via the epsilon production (`M[Term',$] = ε`), which tells you that you can remove that `Term'` node (though that may be optional).

What you end up with for an input string like 3*4 is then a tree like this:

`Term ( Factor(3), Term' (*, Term ( Factor(4) ) ) )`

In a post-processing step, you could simplify the resulting tree, as nonterminals like `Term'` stem from making the grammar non-left-recursive, but are otherwise unsuitable for the resulting AST, so you would want to reverse the grammar transformation on your resulting tree to get something like this:

`Mult (Number(3), Number(4))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, basically you are saying that first i need to create the "parse tree", and then convert it to the AST?. Since the parse tree and the AST of the expression are not the same thing.

Comment: In a sense they are the same thing, however, it is always possible to transform a tree into a more suitable representation. It is called *abstract* for a reason.

Comment: The parse tree often contains symbols that can be omitted from the AST, things such as parentheses, separators, etc.